# How to dynamically create 3d numpy arrays from 2d numpy arrays using for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a 3d numpy array form 2d numpy array using for loop.I tried in many different methods to create 3d arrays from 2d but each time its giving me errors.  This is what I have done, the end array should have a dimension of `(10,3,3)`.

```
#this is a sample code
arr=[]
for i in range(10):
    a=np.random.rand(3,3)
    arr=np.stack(a,arr)
    #arr=np.append(arr,a)
    #arr=np.array([arr,a])
    #arr[i]=a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append the `2d` arrays to the `arr` list using `list.append` method, and after you are done with the for loop, convert `arr` to `3d` array by wrapping it with `np.array`:

```
arr = []
for i in range(10):
    a = np.random.rand(3,3)
    arr.append(a)

np.array(arr).shape
# (10, 3, 3)
```

Or `numpy.stack`:

```
np.stack(arr).shape
# (10, 3, 3)
```